# Mycroft AI can it be ported for ARM processors

Tags: linux

Mycroft AI can it be ported for ARM processors from its openhardware platform for which it is designed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Mycroft AI hardware](https://mycroft.ai/new-design-ubuntu-partnership/) is based around a Raspberry Pi 2, which uses an ARM processor, so the answer is yes, it will work on ARM processors.

Comment: Thanks, my question would be can it be used for anyother ARM based architecture other than RaPi?

Comment: I'd imagine it could be used on other ARM-based architectures, if the target architecture runs Linux and the underlying ARM processor has similar performance characteristics ("ARM-based" covers a very large spectrum). If there are any hardware-specific features, *e.g.* using the LEDs or camera, they would need to be adapted.